# React + Redux - architectural Apis approach

Tags: reactjs, redux, architecture

I have a react app with redux, I two api calls that get the data for me.

The first api call returns a group of questions array.

The seccond api call returns a group of answers for each question

I also have an api call to get the answers for specific question

**First Api Call**

```
{parent: 1, name: "default", id: 36}
{parent: 36, name: "help?", id: 2}
{parent: 36, name: "help me?", id: 3}
{parent: 35, name: "Don't help them?", id: 3}
```

**Second Api Call**

```
{answer: "Yes", questionid: 2, id: 1, question: "help?"}
{answer: "No", questionid: 2, id: 2, question: "help?"}
{answer: "Maybe", questionid: 2, id: 3, question: "help?"}
{answer: "Yes", questionid: 3, id: 1, question: "help me?"}
{answer: "No", questionid: 3, id: 2, question: "help me?"}
```

Data should appear like below

***Group Name: default***

***help? Yes, No, maybe***

***help me? Yes, No***

How can I do this, should I loop for the questions then every question I should loop for the answers, all in two api calls, or I should loop on the questions and every question I should call the api for the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reselect (library) and you could get correct result thanks to that by merging properties in selector. 
https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

It is well normalized state so there is no point in denormalizing it.

So firstly you would get all elements from normalized state and then get all possible results from second API. Iterate through first elements and filter out answers from 2nd API where parentId doesnt equal to id.

Comment: So, It will be two api calls as a total, but what about changing something, If I update on question or an answer, I should call the apis again or just update the state and wait for an error to be thrown from the backend?

Comment: it all depends on you, some people like to update state before being sure if it is alright, some other make some loader before and then await server response. There is no one solution that's best

Comment: Thanks a lot Shiroo!